# Determining when GKSession bluetooth devices go out of range

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, p2p, gksession

I'm using `GKSession, GKSessionDelegate` to implement peer to peer bluetooth connectivity between a number of iX (iPod, iPad, iPhone, ...) devices.  I want to display a list of the currently available/connected devices *in range*.

I'm currently relying on

`- (void)session:(GKSession *)session peer:(NSString *)peerID didChangeState:(GKPeerConnectionState)state`

to do this.  Unfortunately, this method does not appear to be reliably called when a device goes out of range.  Is there a "better" way to determine if a device is in range?

Some code:

```
- (void)session:(GKSession *)session peer:(NSString *)peerID didChangeState:(GKPeerConnectionState)state {

    NSString* connectionStateString=
    (state==GKPeerStateAvailable)?@"available":
    (state==GKPeerStateUnavailable)?@"unavailable":
    (state==GKPeerStateConnected)?@"connected":
    (state==GKPeerStateDisconnected)?@"disconnected":@"connecting";
    // Add the peer to the Dictionary
    NSArray* details=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[session displayNameForPeer:peerID],connectionStateString,nil];
    [connectionPeers setObject:details forKey:peerID];

    if (state == GKPeerStateAvailable) {
        NSLog(@"Adding peerID:%@",peerID);
        [session connectToPeer:peerID withTimeout:60];//'connect' to everything, so data can be sent
    }
    else if (state == GKPeerStateUnavailable || state==GKPeerStateDisconnected) {
        [connectionPeers removeObjectForKey:peerID];
    }
    [self listPlayers];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GKSession is built on Bonjour over Bluetooth and I believe that your problem is that the bonjour service is still showing as active since Bonjour doesn't invalidate service advertisements when a peer has disconnected from the network. I think the mDNS records only expire either when the mDNS cache timeout occurs ( not something you can tweak ) or when the advertising peer manually invalidates the service.

I don't think GKSession is going to easily do what you want here via advertisement. Connected peers should however disconnect once they're out of Bluetooth range.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Mark.  I solved this by periodically sending messages to all devices, and listening for the response.  If I didn't get a response, I removed the device from the 'connected' list.  I did not reliably get a 'disconnected' state change indicating that devices where out of range, which was the whole problem.  I still think my solution is pretty horrible, and am hopeful that there is a better way.

Comment: GKSession over bluetooth is horrible ;)  I recommend looking into BTLE and the CoreBluetooth API going forward.

Comment: Thanks for that @Mark.  I think I will.  GKSession BT didn't do what I wanted--the range was too good!  I wanted something approximating line-of-sight.  BTLE sounds like it will be good for that, and also communicating between different devices (eg android).

Comment: CoreBluetooth will give you rssi as well, which will give you an approximation of distance, even if you're in signal range.

Comment: OK @Mark, so it seems the answer is 'no there is not a better way when using GKSession' (because GKSession is crap).  Thanks!